# How to create load more in search result with vue js and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to create function load more in my search result with vue js and laravel.

This is what I try.
My form code to search

```
<form @submit.prevent="search">
    <input v-model="term" type="search">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

here is to show search result

```
<tr v-for="(result, index) in results.data">
    <td>{{ result.artist_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.gender }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.updated_at }}</td>
</tr>
<div v-if="results.next_page_url" class="card-footer">
<button @click.prevent="paginatesearch(results.next_page_url)" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>
```

here is my data variable

```
data() {
return {
    term:'',
    results:[],
 }
},
```

Here is my code to showing search result.

```
search() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('term', this.term);
        axios.post('/api/artist/search/', formData)
        .then((response) => {
        this.SearchDiv = true;
        this.IndexDiv = false;
        this.results = response.data;
        this.noResults = this.results.length === 0;
        });
    },
```

and this is my code to show load more data

```
paginatesearch(url = '') {
this.loading = true;
this.disabled = 1;
axios.get(url ? url : '/api/artist/search/')
.then(response => {
this.loading = false;
this.disabled = 0;
if (! this.results.data) {
    this.results = response.data
}
else {
    this.results.data.push(...response.data.data)
    this.results.next_page_url = response.data.next_page_url
}
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
},
```

But when I click the button, it give me

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Here is my full code if u need it https://github.com/jazuly1/nginx/blob/master/loadmorewithsearch.vue

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.results.push(...response.data.data)`? Also, since `this.results` is an array, you probably don't want to be adding properties like `next_page_url` as Vue will not treat them reactively

Comment: i got this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. im not sure, cause code above is working with index data.

Comment: @Phil its a little working i change `get` from `axios.get` to `post`, it can be load now, but it load all data, not based on what i search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need a simple correction..

in `search` method change `axios.post('/api/artist/search/', formData)` to `axios.post('/api/artist/search/' + this.$data.term)`

and in `paginatesearch` method change `axios.get` to `axios.post`.

and some correction in `controller` page. now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

'results'is defined as an array, but is used as an object.